# Using a progress meter for file upload and form processing

Tags: jquery, css, forms, progress-bar, semantic-ui

My problem is that measuring file upload doesn't measure the backend processing of files, so the progress meter fills to 100 % and then you have to wait even more for the server backend processing of the files before the response.

I can add a progress meter with [semantic-ui](/questions/tagged/semantic-ui) and make it fill during file upload, but then file processing takes longer time and makes you wait for the response from the server even though file upload is done. I'm considering refactoring the whole solution and maybe use a waiting symbol instead and/or deactivate (grey out) the whole page and print "please wait..." while uploading + processing the files.

Is that a good idea? The code is from the semantic-ui framework (progress meter) and the [page](http://qlbusiness.com/ai) is online if you want to have a look and try the actual server response and file processing.

Another idea was to use two progress meters, is that better?

```
    $(function () {

        var bar = $('.bar');
        var percent = $('.percent');
        var status = $('#status');

        $('form').ajaxForm({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/upload/ahFkZXZ-bW9udGFvcHJvamVjdHIiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICAoPoIDA',
            beforeSend: function () {
                status.empty();
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            complete: function (xhr) {
                $('#wrapper').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    });
```